# Is it a good idea to send data to two fragments from the same activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, parcelable

Below is a snapshot of the activity code. I want to send the lists to separate fragments. The first one works fine, however in   stepsFragment.setArguments(stepsBundle); setArguments isn't recognized. thank you.

```
//
// Send the ingredients array list in Parcelable to the Ingredients Fragment
//
private void sendArrayToIngredientsFragment() {
    //Pack Data in a bundle(call the bundle "ingredientsBundle" to differentiate it from the "stepsBundle"
    Bundle ingredientsBundle = new Bundle();
    ingredientsBundle.putParcelable("Recipes", recipes);

    //Pass Over the bundle to the Ingredients Fragment
    IngredientsFragment ingredientsFragment = new IngredientsFragment();
    ingredientsFragment.setArguments(ingredientsBundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ingredients_fragment_container, ingredientsFragment).commit();
}

/*
  Send the steps array list in Parcelable to the Steps Fragment
  */
private void sendArrayToStepsFragment() {
    //Pack Data in a bundle(call the bundle "stepsBundle" to differentiate it from the "ingredientsBundle"
    Bundle stepsBundle = new Bundle();
    stepsBundle.putParcelable("Recipes", recipes);

    //Pass Over the bundle to the Steps Fragment
    StepsFragment stepsFragment = new StepsFragment();
    stepsFragment.setArguments(stepsBundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.steps_fragment_container, stepsFragment).commit();
}
```

}

Comment: whats the issue with `stepsFragment.setArguments` ? Yes you can pass data to your fragment. Recommended way to create one static method in fragment class itself say 
 public static Fragment newInstance(<your data>) {
        <Fragment class> fragment = <Fragment class>;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        // add data to bundle
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

Comment: the message is: setArguments not recognized.

Comment: If you haven't figured out the answer yet, it may help to post the code for `StepsFragment`

Comment: Thanks. I already figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Take sure, your fragment classes both extends from Fragment class. If that so, there must be method setArguments()